# How to use nested template in Iron-router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

One page of my app `should` look like this:

```
|                   header                           |
|     sidebarmenu01         main01                   |
|     sidebarmenu01         main01                   |
|     sidebarmenu01         main01                   |
|     sidebarmenu01         main01                   |
|                   footer                           |
```

So I defined 2 templates:

1) `ApplicationLayout.html` -> Application Layout: header, main, footer

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout'
})

<template name="ApplicationLayout">
  {{> header}}
  <div class="main">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
  {{> footer}}
</template>
```

2) `Page01Layout.html` -> layout for the above page.

```
Page01Controller = RouteController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: 'Page01Layout',
});

this.route('/page01/main01', {
  template: 'Page01Main01',
  controller: Page01Controller,
});

<template name="Page01Layout">
  <div class="page01 sidebar menu">
    {{> yield SidebarMenu}}
  </div>
  <div class="page01 main">
    {{> yield }}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="Page01Main01">
  <div> main 01 </div>
</template>
```

But what I got looks like this:

```
|     sidebarmenu01         main01                   |
|     sidebarmenu01         main01                   |
|     sidebarmenu01         main01                   |
|     sidebarmenu01         main01                   |
```

The ApplicationLayout is ignored.

How can I get what I want?

Comment: Looks like you're overwriting the previous `ApplicationLayout` with `Page01Layout`. So when your route sets up the view it doesn't even use `ApplicationLayout`. Drop the controller from the route and work from that - that would be my start.

Comment: Yes, is there any way to put Page01Layout inside ApplicationLayout?